# Hiding the Edit and delete button in a DataTable based on the identity value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have the following dataTable. I want to hide the button Edit and delete based on the Identity Value returned from the controller.

```js
<script>
    var Popup, dataTable;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable =  $("#BookAssignmentTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/bookAssign/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Book" },
                { "data": "Office" },
                { "data": "Group", "width":"100px"},
                {
                    "data": "ID",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("StoreOrEdit", "BookAssign")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Edit</a> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>Delete</a>";
                    },
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "150px",
                    "Visible":"false"
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable" : "No data found please click on <b>Add New </b> Button"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is my controller:

```js
public ActionResult Index() {
    var id = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;
    return View();
}

if (id== "test1")
```

then I want to hide the Edit and Delete button. Is it possible to do that in DataTable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, change following code:

```
"data": "ID", "render": function (data) {

                            return "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("StoreOrEdit", "BookAssign")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Edit</a> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>Delete</a>";
                        },
```

With something like this:

```
"data": "ID", "render": function(data) {

    if (data == "test") {
        return "";
    } else {    
        return "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("StoreOrEdit", "BookAssign")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Edit</a> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>Delete</a>";
    }
},
```

Comment: A little detail. Just add a 1 at the end of test value, because OP is sending **test1** not just **test**. Good answer by the way.